# How does engine braking mapping work?

Tags: engine-theory, fuel-consumption, electronics

Some recent cars and a lot of bikes can change engine mapping and change engine braking electronically. For instance, my bike is not an automatic bike, so it has mechanical gears and I am able to electronically choose 3 levels of engine braking.

From my understanding, engine mapping consists in changing the proportion of fuel and air depending on a lot of parameter (gas throttle, pressure, temperature, RPM, exhaust data...). During engine break, from what I heard/read, no fuel is injected.

So, how does engine braking mapping work? Does the bike/car inject fuel during engine braking in order to lower it? Or does it change other parameters I'm not aware of?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure this question is on topic here, if it's not feel free to tell me and I'll try to rephrase it so it will be on topic.

Comment: Engine Theory questions are on topic here. I'm not quite sure if this can be answered, though, mainly because I don't think "one size fits all", meaning, it probably depends on how the engineers develop the mapping for any given engine. Also, while most cars have a level of engine braking, its not really user adjustable as you are describing for your bike.

Comment: I changed a bit my question so it's more answerable. I removed the consumption part because it's a different question and as you said, it will vary depending on the brand.

Comment: Engine mapping involves much more than just fuel delivery...

Comment: @SolarMike maybe I understood wrong, but from what I understood it's about how much gas and air you put depending on a lot of parameters. So, in the end, how to change the engine behavior when there is no fuel injected? Unless I'm wrong on how mapping works and explaining how it works will probably answer my question